# element occur at specified number

Tags: xml, xsd

here is my xml document

```
<root>
 <num>3</num>
 <a>
  <b>
   <c n="m"></c>
   <c></c>
   <c n="e"></c>
  </b>
  <b>
   <c n="s"></c>
   <c n="w"></c>
   <c></c>
  </b>
  <b>
   <c n="q"></c>
   <c></c>
   <c n="u"></c>
  </b>
 </a>
</root>
```

I want to created a xml Schema.
Element c in b must occurs only n time.(n is in num element)
I think it use key, keyref or unique.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible.

Key, keyref and unique will not help. Unique will ensure that you have no duplicate items. And key and keyref will ensure that the elements in place B match those in place A.

The maxOccurs restriction requires a simple integer argument. It is not possible to calculate the integer by any kind of Xpath expression. See here: http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-0/#OccurrenceConstraints

**Update**

If you want to solve your problem with unique, key and key ref you have to create an number index in an attribute. The following image illustrates the schema:

[image]

You have to add an attribute to your `c` nodes which references a master attribute index. In this example it is stored in multiple num elements. You can put an integer restriction, a unique and a key constrain on `/root/num@count`. After that you create a reference constrain from `/root/a/b/c@count` to `/root/num@count`. This will create a max constrain. You can have as many `c` nodes as `num` nodes but you can have less, too.

This is the schema:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified" attributeFormDefault="unqualified">
  <xs:element name="root">
    <xs:annotation>
      <xs:documentation>Comment describing your root element</xs:documentation>
    </xs:annotation>
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="num" maxOccurs="unbounded">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:attribute name="count" type="xs:unsignedInt" use="required"/>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
        <xs:element name="a" maxOccurs="unbounded">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:element name="b" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                <xs:complexType>
                  <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element name="c" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                      <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:attribute name="count" type="xs:integer" use="required"/>
                      </xs:complexType>
                    </xs:element>
                  </xs:sequence>
                </xs:complexType>
              </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:unique name="num_unique">
      <xs:selector xpath="num"/>
      <xs:field xpath="@count"/>
    </xs:unique>
    <xs:key name="num_key">
      <xs:selector xpath="num"/>
      <xs:field xpath="@count"/>
    </xs:key>
    <xs:keyref name="num_ref" refer="num_key">
      <xs:selector xpath="a/b/c"/>
      <xs:field xpath="@count"/>
    </xs:keyref>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

And this would be a valid file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="root.xsd">
  <num count="1"/>
  <num count="2"/>
  <num count="3"/>
  <a>
    <b>
      <c count="1"/>
    </b>
    <b>
      <c count="1"/>
      <c count="2"/>
    </b>
  </a>
</root>
```

It will become invalid if you add a `<c count="4"/>`. Right now I have no idea how to make it an identity reference. Maybe it is possible to reverse the reference direction...

*But never the less it is no good idea to place a constrain into the same file as the data itself.* If you do not trust your data source it does not make much sense to ask your data source for a self given constrain. You must put the constrain into the schema or extend the validation by some kind of program logic. For example you can count the number of all `c` nodes in their parent and check if they are all the same or are all equal to a given number. That would make much more sense, because that is the only secure way to enforce the constrain.

Comment: so only way is maxOccurs="unbounded"